# Start, stop and restart service menu options are disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to start my sql server instance but apparently, the menu options for starting, stopping and restarting the instance are disabled. What I did to learn this was to right click my instance on the `Object Explorer` and I instantly saw these three was disabled as seen in the image below:

[image]

I checked with the SQL Server Configuration Manager regarding the status of the services and it seems their start mode are all set as Automatic. I'm not sure though if I checked the right part but here is what they look like:

[image]

I don't know what else to check but any information will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try running SSMS with the Run as Administrator option.

Comment: I just fixed it. I stopped everything in the configuration manager, set it to manual start mode, ran the service that I need and logged in the management studio. The menu items weren't disabled anymore

Comment: That doesn't feel like a fix. Look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62501/minimum-permission-to-restart-sql-services) answer.

Comment: Well it does fix what I need for now. Anyway its just a personal service that I'm using right now so that will do for me. I think I'll use what you posted when this is used for production. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I just got the solution. I did the following:

1. I stopped the service that I need to use in the `Sql Server Configuration Manager`
2. Set the `Start Mode` of that service to Manual
3. Started the required service
4. Logged in to my server in the `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`
5. Right clicked on the server from the `Object Explorer` window

After that, the menu items weren't disabled anymore

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected to the Sql Server Management Studio as the user with rights to start/stop/restart the server?
Could you please try to connect as sa-user?

Comment: I just tried but its still the same. I'll try to stop everything in the configuration manager and set it to manual. Hopefully that fixes it